# Django 1.9: Create complex custom filter method for QuerySet

Tags: python, sql, django, filter, django-queryset

The goal is to create a `custom_filter` method that can be chained to standard Django filter methods. The `custom_filter` method likely requires some raw SQL code. In the best case, the *QuerySet* would still be evaluated lazy.

In the end, such a command would be great:

```
apple_query_set = Apple.objects.filter(<any standard filtering>).custom_filter()
```

This is the model:

```
class Apple(models.model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

The goal of the `custom_filter` is to group the Apple instances by `(a,b)`, and for each
group return only the newest instance according to `date`.

The raw SQL code for such a filter is as follows:

```
custom_filter_raw_sql = """
SELECT t1.id
FROM app_apple AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT a, b, max(date) AS max_date
            FROM app_apple
            GROUP BY a, b) AS t2
ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t1.date = t2.max_date;
"""
```

So far, in order to add the `custom_filter` functionality, 
 I've tried (unsuccessfully) adding `objects = AppleQuerySet.as_manager()` to the Apple class, with:

```
 class AppleQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def custom_filter(self):
        subquery = """
        SELECT t1.id
        FROM app_apple AS t1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT a, b, max(date) AS max_date
                    FROM app_apple
                    GROUP BY a, b) AS t2
        """
        condition = "t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t1.date = t2.max_date"
        return self.extra(tables=[subquery], where=[condition])
```

However, I'm not sure this approach stands a chance to work, as the custom query 
 should not only work on all Apple instances (`Apple.objects.`), but it should be possible to chain it to a filtered queryset (`Apple.objects.filter()`)

What is the best approach to create this custom chainable, (lazy) `custom_filter` functionality? Where am I going wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't [perform raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) directly by using all the filter conditions in the query itself?

Comment: @AKS This may be a solution, but I wouldn't know how to make sure that the SQL code can be arbitrarily chained to the QuerySet (instead of doing a filter on the entire Apple table). I'd be happy to see some code how to do this. (Also, I'm not sure this solution allows for lazy evaluation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative way, but I wonder if you could only use a combination of [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) and [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) to achieve the desired results:

```
Apple.objects.order_by('a', 'b', '-date').distinct('a', 'b')
```

This combination works if you keep the ordering of fields same in `order_by` and `distinct`.

And, this way you can also user the chained `filter` beforehand if you need to.

**Some explanation:**

Using following will only put all the objects with similar `a` and `b` together

```
Apple.objects.order_by('a', 'b')
```

But, you can order the objects in a group (with same `a` and `b` values) further by `-date` (in decreasing order)

```
Apple.objects.order_by('a', 'b', '-date')
```

Now, all the objects which have similar `a` and `b` are together and in each group first element has the latest `date`. So, we can keep the ones at the top by using `distinct('a', 'b')`

```
Apple.objects.order_by('a', 'b', '-date').distinct('a', 'b')
```

Comment: This is an elegant answer! @AKS, do you think the (in this case certainly) clumsy approach via custom SQL to add a filter chain step is technically possible? In case, is there example code somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @elke, Is there a particular reason you insist on the approach you mentioned? I say this because what you want as result can be easily achieved using the existing django functionalities as above.

Comment: @ AKS, for the exact above example, your approach is definitely to be preferred. My thinking was just that perhaps if another user stumbles across this article, an answer to "how can a similarly complex sql query be inserted to a queryset filter" is perhaps what she'd be searching for, and not the solution to my particular example problem. Perhaps however, all problems have such elegant solutions in the end?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is a custom manager. Check it out on [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/managers/)

Here you can see an example, using raw SQL code:

```
from django.db import models

class PollManager(models.Manager):
    def with_counts(self):
        from django.db import connection
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT p.id, p.question, p.poll_date, COUNT(*)
            FROM polls_opinionpoll p, polls_response r
            WHERE p.id = r.poll_id
            GROUP BY p.id, p.question, p.poll_date
            ORDER BY p.poll_date DESC""")
        result_list = []
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            p = self.model(id=row[0], question=row[1], poll_date=row[2])
            p.num_responses = row[3]
            result_list.append(p)
        return result_list
```

Comment: How would this solution look like if the returned value should be a QuerySet? Can the method be applied as a chained filter (instead of rerunning the query on the entire Apple table?). Does this solution allow for lazy evaluation?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager 

Here it's shown how to create custom querysets from your custom manager and it should answer the two first questions. I don't know what do you mean with "allow for lazy evaluation"